# actionNext & textMultiline not working

Tags: android, xml, imeoptions

I want a `Multiline` `EditText` to allow `imeOptions="actionNext"`.

---

This works, but only allows single line input

```
<EditText>
    ...
    android:inputType="textCapSentences|textAutoCorrect"
    android:imeOptions="actionNext"
    ...
</EditText>
```

This changes the `imeOption` to an enter key.

```
<EditText>
    ...
    android:inputType="textCapSentences|textAutoCorrect|textMultiline"
    android:imeOptions="actionNext" <!-- Why is this code skipped? -->
    ...
</EditText>
```

*The Google Keep and Gmail apps do this somehow, so don't tell me it isn't possible.*

Comment: Have same issue. Did you get the solution?

Comment: @AnkurRaiyani I do not remember the case I was trying to perform this, but I think I uses a different `imeOption` and `setOnEditorActionListener` on the `EditText` in Java

Answer (score 4):

The enter key can only do one thing: enter new line to the editor or move cursor to the next field. One way to implement this is have the enter key move to the next field but still allow text in the editor to auto-wrap.

In XML:

```
<EditText
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:text="@string/default_label_a"
    android:selectAllOnFocus="true"
    android:maxLines="5"
    android:imeOptions="actionNext"
/>
```

In code:

```
edittext.setHorizontallyScrolling(false);
edittext.setMaxLines(Integer.MAX_VALUE);
```